# Node + Angular: Response header isn't being passed in requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cookies

I'm having a problem getting the cookie with my auth token to pass as part of my requests. When I look in Chrome after my authentication request is fulfilled, the response cookie is appropriately set, but it is never passed into additional requests.

Express route for /login that generates the cookie:

```
router.get('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    session: false
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    console.log('/login authentication successful');
    token.generate(req.users, function(result) {
      res.cookie('access_token', result, {
        //secure : true,
        //maxAge : 1000*60*60, // 1 hour
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true
      });
      res.json(Response.success(req.user));
    });
  }
);
```

I also have the following for setting the headers:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    next();
  });
```

Now in Angular, I am passing a config object to my $http request with **withCredentials: true**, but so far, nothing has worked.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/devices',
  withCredentials: true
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  // do stuff
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
  // oh noes!
});
```

A note about my setup: I have one node server running to provide the backend on port 3000, with another node server using browserSync to display the clientside on port 8080. I've seen a suggestion that using http://localhost:8080 instead of an IP could cause the cookie to not get passed, but that doesn't appear to make a difference.

Hopefully one of you fine guys or gals will have an inkling as to what my problem is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

seem to be missing header for `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` which would include verbs used `"OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,DELETE"` etc

Reference [MDN HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Methods)

I don't use node a lot for cors but I know there are packages that will do all this for you